# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\views\Useraccount\Userlist.php on line 38

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I get error  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
my controller name is Useraccount

```
function userList() {   
   $result['data'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list();
   $data['userlist']=$result['data'] ;
   $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
}
```

and model name is Useraccount_mod

```
function getUser_list() {
    $query=$this->db->query("select * from users");
    return $query->result();
}
```

and view name is Userlist

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    if ($userlist > 0) {
        foreach ($userlist as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>                                        
                <td width="100"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td> 
                <td width="100"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td> 
                <td width="100"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td> 
                <td width="100"><?php echo $row['creatdate']; ?></td> 
                <td width="100"><?php echo $row['updateddate']; ?></td> 
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>No Record Found</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>   Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
>   Filename: Useraccount/Userlist.php
>   Line Number: 38
>   Backtrace:

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried to debug or even solve this problem?

Comment: my question is how to remove  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **result()** function to fetch records, but this give records as object not as array. If you want to get array than you will have to use **result_array()**.

```
function userList() {   
   $data['userlist'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list();
   $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
}
```

> Method 1:

```
function getUser_list() {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from users")->result_array(); //here we can use result() as well but it gives object not array
  return $query;
}


<tbody>
  <?php
  if ($userlist > 0) {
      foreach ($userlist as $row) {
          ?>
          <tr>                                        
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row['creatdate']; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row['updateddate']; ?></td> 
          </tr>
          <?php
      }
  } else {
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>No Record Found</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

> Method 2:

```
function getUser_list() {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from users")->result(); 
  return $query;
}


<tbody>
  <?php
  if ($userlist > 0) {
      foreach ($userlist as $row) {
          ?>
          <tr>                                        
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row->username; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row->address; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row->creatdate; ?></td> 
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row->updateddate; ?></td> 
          </tr>
          <?php
      }
  } else {
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>No Record Found</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks bro for your valueable answer  but I have done it